# NSURLConnection appends random characters to the response

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsurlconnection

At one place in my app, I initialize an asynchronous request using NSURLConnection:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.URLs objectForKey:@"API URL"]]
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
apiConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[request release];
```

and fetch the result:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if (responseData == nil) {
        responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"%s", [data bytes]);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes random data is being appended to the actual data returned by the server. Sometimes, the log message as well as the actual output (after conversion to a NSString object in `connectionDidFinishLoading:connection`) contain some part of some header, "CFNetwork" or just arbitrary bytes/characters.

Is this a known bug? Has anyone encountered this before and knows how to work around this? Is there anything I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append '0' character to limit the string if you use it as an c-String (null terminator).

From one of my projects:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   char temp[] = {0};
   [receivedData appendBytes:temp length:1];

   // etc your usual code here
}
```

Gave me *a lot* of headaches, too.

Comment: Sometimes the answer can be so simple... Thanks for the fast reply!